# Jtable with two jComboBoxes freezing, greying out some fields, and losing rendering

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jtable, jcombobox

[jtable w/ 2 jcomboboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx4mR.jpg)

Using Netbeans 7.0.1, jDK 6, and Toplink Essentials (JPA 1) to build a Java Database Application with a Java DB (embedded) server. Created a Master/Detail Form choosing the detail area as textfields format option(seen above).  Problems abound when a second jComboBox is added to the jTable. One works fine so maybe it’s how the default table model sequences commands or sump’in like that.  The following errors are created once a selection is made from a second combobox (doesnt matter which one but the order of being second that cause):

-some components in the application to freeze once mouse is released and others are no longer selectable.

-some fields in the lower form (they’re all bound to the upper table in the form) go grey as seen above including notes which is just a textfield not associated with the combobox except that it’s bound to the table(command sequencing?).

-on restart the comboboxes that have been selected no longer render and the corresponding Author/Genre fields below have become blank

I’m a complete beginner who started this venture with a few tutorials including [Creating a Custom Java Desktop Database Application](http://OrigCreating%20a%20Custom%20Java%20Desktop%20Database%20Application%20-%20NetBeans%206.5%20Tutorial.pdf) to teach this old dog something new. This particular snag is becoming my nemesis. Every new approach ends in a thud.  Help would be mucho apreciado!  Here’s the bones.

**Tables:** changed everything to lowercase which ultimately corrected rendering not working when second combo box was added.  However, as noted above it stops working once an item in the second combobox is selected.

```
CREATE TABLE app.genres (
id          INTEGER NOT NULL
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
genre VARCHAR(20),
CONSTRAINT genre_PK PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);
CREATE TABLE app.authors (
id          INTEGER NOT NULL 
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
            (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
firstname VARCHAR(15),
middlename VARCHAR(15),
lastname VARCHAR(15),
CONSTRAINT author_PK PRIMARY KEY (id) 
 );
CREATE TABLE app.books (
id          INTEGER NOT NULL 
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
            (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
markread VARCHAR(5),
title VARCHAR(100),
authorid INTEGER,
genreid INTEGER,
notes VARCHAR(255),
Constraint book_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE app.books ADD CONSTRAINT genre_FK Foreign Key (genreid)
REFERENCES app.genres (id);
ALTER TABLE app.books ADD CONSTRAINT author_FK Foreign Key (authorid)
REFERENCES app.authors (id);
```

**Entity classes**: Selected "generate named query annotations for persistent fields", "generate jaxb annotations"- JAXB, “Attributes for Regenerating Tables, and “Use Column Names in Relationships”. Set Association fetch to eager and Collection Type to list (although I tried alternate settings to no avail).
The Books entity class required the following changes:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "GENREID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Genres genreid;
...
/**  delete duplicate
@Column(name = "GENREID")
 private Integer genreid;
**/
...
//Replace Integer with Genres, authorsid did not have these errors
public Genres getGenreid() {
    return genreid;
}

public void setGenreid(Genres genreid) {
    Genres oldGenreid = this.genreid;
    this.genreid = genreid;
    changeSupport.firePropertyChange("genreid", oldGenreid, genreid);
}
/**deleting the duplicate
  public Genres getGenreid() {
    return genreid;
}
```

**Renderer**: (Genres is the same with the few editing needs):

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JList;

 public class CBListCellRendererAuthors extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    if (value instanceof Authors) {
        Authors a = (Authors) value;
       setText(a.getFirstname()+(" ")+a.getMiddlename()+(" ")+a.getLastname());
    }
    return this;
}   
}
```

**jComboBox:**
Changed properties renderer to the matching class and bound the comboboxes to the corresponding database tables.

**jTable:** Changes in the Table Contents, Columns, Customizer Dialog
- “Editors” settings: added

```
new DefaultCellEditor(jComboBoxAuthors) --or Genres
```

- “Expressions”: A number of tutorials show changing this to
  ${genreid.genre}  --or author settings but...
  This worked great with one combobox.  Did not work with two so had to leave it set to the default
- “Type”: would normally become string but I gave up trying to get two renderers to work via the customizer dialog settings and cobbling together some code which meant changing type to the following
  main.Genres (or main.Authors)

**Source code**: added the following after the constructor

```
TableColumn tc = masterTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    TableColumn tc2 = masterTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    DefaultCellEditor de=new DefaultCellEditor(jComboBoxAuthors);
    tc.setCellEditor(de);
    DefaultCellEditor de2=new DefaultCellEditor(jComboBoxGenres);
    tc2.setCellEditor(de2);
}
```

**One of many promising attempts**: Implemented the action/listener/handler steps from a very informative tutorial How to Build a GUI but still couldn’t figure out how to get that to correct the rendering issues.  Of course as a complete novice my coding is likely chuck full of muckity muck and misses.  Again appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

**Output:** once combox is clicked

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException
at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3047)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.convertForward(Binding.java:1312)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.getSourceValueForTarget(Binding.java:844)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.refreshUnmanaged(Binding.java:1222)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.refresh(Binding.java:1207)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.tryRefreshThenSave(AutoBinding.java:162)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.sourceChangedImpl(AutoBinding.java:227)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.sourceChanged(Binding.java:1411)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.access$1200(Binding.java:38)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding$PSL.propertyStateChanged(Binding.java:1618)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.PropertyHelper.firePropertyStateChange(PropertyHelper.java:212)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.notifyListeners(ELProperty.java:688)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.access$800(ELProperty.java:155)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty$SourceEntry.processSourceChanged(ELProperty.java:312)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty$SourceEntry.sourceChanged(ELProperty.java:326)
at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty$SourceEntry.propertyChange(ELProperty.java:333)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:339)
at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:276)
at org.jdesktop.swingbinding.adapters.BeanAdapterBase.firePropertyChange(BeanAdapterBase.java:112)
at org.jdesktop.swingbinding.adapters.JTableAdapterProvider$Adapter$Handler.tableSelectionChanged(JTableAdapterProvider.java:81)
at org.jdesktop.swingbinding.adapters.JTableAdapterProvider$Adapter$Handler.valueChanged(JTableAdapterProvider.java:91)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:167)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:147)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:194)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:388)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:398)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:442)
at javax.swing.JTable.changeSelectionModel(JTable.java:2347)
at javax.swing.JTable.changeSelection(JTable.java:2416)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.adjustSelection(BasicTableUI.java:1085)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:1008)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:263)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6411)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4276)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others I'm posting what worked for me. Note, its likely not proper since I have no training in programming. Created an Sqlite database by downloading the free open source SQLite Studio from sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt?act=download. Downloaded [rs2xml.jar](http://superb-dca2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/finalangelsanddemons/rs2xml.jar) and [sqlitejdbcv056jar](http://www.java2s.com/code/jar/s/downloadsqlitejdbcv056jar.htm). Created a NetBeans java application project. Added both jars to the projects library. In the project created a java class to connect to the database:

```
public class connectjava {
    Connection conn= null;

public static Connection ConnecrDb(){
    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://ThePathToYourDatabase/TheNameOfYourDatabase.db");
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
}

public Connection getConn() {
    return conn;
}

public void setConn(Connection conn) {
    this.conn = conn;
}
}
```

Created a JFrame Form. Dragged a JTable onto the form. Added this code:

```
public class CollectionBooksTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn, concb, concb2, conck = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
Statement stcb, stcb2, stck = null;

/** Creates new form CollectionBooks */
public CollectionBooksTest() {
    initComponents();
    conn = connectjava.ConnecrDb();
    PopulateJTable();
}

private void PopulateJTable() {
    //jComboBox One part 1/2
    Vector cbItems = new Vector();
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        concb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://ThePathToYourDatabase/TheNameOfYourDatabase.db");
        stcb = concb.createStatement();
        String sqlcb = "SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname FROM authors ORDER BY lastname ASC";
        ResultSet rscb = stcb.executeQuery(sqlcb);
        int row = 0;
        while ((rscb != null) && (rscb.next())) {
            cbItems.add(rscb.getString("firstname") + " " + rscb.getString("middlename") + " " + rscb.getString("lastname"));
        }
        rscb.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (stcb != null) {
            stcb.close();
            concb.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //jComboBox One part 2/2
    DefaultComboBoxModel cbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(cbItems);
    final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(cbm);

    //jComboBox Two part 1/2
    Vector cb2Items = new Vector();
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        concb2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://ThePathToYourDatabase/TheNameOfYourDatabase.db");
        stcb2 = concb2.createStatement();
        String sqlcb2 = "SELECT genre FROM genres ORDER BY genre ASC";
        ResultSet rscb2 = stcb2.executeQuery(sqlcb2);
        int row = 0;
        while ((rscb2 != null) && (rscb2.next())) {
            cb2Items.add(rscb2.getString("genre"));
        }
        rscb2.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (stcb2 != null) {
            stcb2.close();
            concb2.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //jComboBox Two part 2/2
    DefaultComboBoxModel cb2model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(cb2Items);
    final JComboBox cb2 = new JComboBox(cb2model);


    //populate jTable adding comboboxes, etc
    String sql = "Select markread as 'Read', title as 'Title', authorid as 'Author', genreid as 'Genre', notes as 'Notes' from books";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        jTable1_pumpdata.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        jTable1_pumpdata.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        //add checkbox
        CheckBoxRenderer rchb = new CheckBoxRenderer();
        jTable1_pumpdata.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(rchb);
        JCheckBox chb = new JCheckBox();
        chb.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        TableColumn tchb = jTable1_pumpdata.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        DefaultCellEditor e = new DefaultCellEditor(chb);
        tchb.setCellEditor(e);
        //add comboboxes
        TableColumn tcb = jTable1_pumpdata.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        DefaultCellEditor e2 = new DefaultCellEditor(cb);
        tcb.setCellEditor(e2);
        TableColumn tcb2 = jTable1_pumpdata.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
        DefaultCellEditor e3 = new DefaultCellEditor(cb2);
        tcb2.setCellEditor(e3);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

For those interested in the checkbox. Added a rendererer at the very end of the code:

```
private class CheckBoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

    CheckBoxRenderer() {
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        setSelected((value != null && ((Boolean) value).booleanValue()));
        return this;
    }
}
}
```